# gapi login state not retained in users browser after page refresh

Tags: javascript, authentication, browser, oauth-2.0, google-api-js-client

I've dove into a small project aiming to utilize the YouTube API. I've got some basic code in place, that I initially thought was, working properly.

Using Chrome, I can login through multiple machines on my own network without any issues using the source below. I've also tethered my machines to my cellular network to ensure that the process also works properly outside of my own network.

Unfortunately, **I'm having issues finding out why a colleague (from a remote location) is unable to retain his login state between page refreshes after successfully logging in through Chrome**, although no issues are apparent when using Firefox.

For an example of a successful scenario, when loading the page for the first time, the callback assigned to `authInstance.isSignedIn.listen` is called with a value of `true` if the user has already logged in.

On my colleagues machine, the `authInstance.isSignedIn.listen` listener is not called after refreshing the page after successfully logging in, indicating no login.

I'm currently not using an SSL certificate, if that information helps any.

Additional information includes my colleagues ability to authenticate and retain login state without any issues on other sites that support YouTube authentication. I've been unable to look through the source of those sites, as the source is obfuscated.

Here's my own source:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoad" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="sign-in">Sign In</button>
    <button id="sign-out">Sign Out</button>
    <script>
        var authInstance;
        var signInBtn = document.getElementById('sign-in');
        var signOutBtn = document.getElementById('sign-out');

        function onLoad() {
            gapi.load('auth2', function() {
                console.log('loadAuth2()');
                auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                    client_id: '[CLIENT_ID]',
                });

                authInstance = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
                authInstance.isSignedIn.listen(function () {
                    console.log('authUpdate()');
                    console.log(arguments);
                });
            });
        }

        signInBtn.onclick = function () {
            console.log('signInBtn onclick()');

            /*

            Signing in this way produces the same results.

            auth2.grantOfflineAccess({
              scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly",
              redirect_uri: "postmessage"
            }).then(function () {
                console.log("accessGranted() (?)");
                console.log(arguments);
            });

            */

            auth2.signIn({
                scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube",
            }).then(function () {
                console.log('signedIn()');
                console.log(arguments);
            });
        };

        signOutBtn.onclick = function () {
            console.log('signOutBtn onclick()');
            authInstance.signOut();
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm also having this issue - were you able to solve it?

Comment: Unfortunately wasn't able to. I didn't have convenient access to the problem machine. I wasn't able to repro the issue anywhere else.

Comment: I am noticing this issue on my Chrome Browser. I have several accounts logged in and when I go to authorize I have to choose for which account. I'm curious if having multiple accounts is the issue? I finally tried on Safari and logged in as one user and now when I refresh the page it doesn't ask to authorize each time.

Also, if I use an incognito window in chrome works as well.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert in Google Sign-In, in my experience, however, the following code did not work.

```
authInstance = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
console.log(authInstance.isSignedIn.get());
```

Instead, you should do like:

```
authInstance = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
authInstance.then(function() {  // onInit
  console.log(authInstance.isSignedIn.get());
}, function() {  // onError
});
```

You should wait until the `GoogleAuth` object is fully initialized.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it for me! 
My code now looks like
`const getGoogleAccessToken = async () => {
  gapi.client.init({
    'clientId': CLIENT_ID,
    'scope': scope,
  })

  const authInstance = await gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
  if(!authInstance.isSignedIn.get()) {
    await authInstance.signIn()
  }

  return authInstance.currentUser.get().getAuthResponse().access_token
}`

Comment: @user553965 You would better write another answer rather than the comment.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I got it to work with a custom button which you attach the event to. Yes its very important to await some of these functions as mentioned by other answers, as perhaps not everything has loaded untill they have been awaited

```
async function initializeGoogleStuff() {
  window.gapi.load('auth2', async () => {
    window.auth2 = await window.gapi.auth2.init({
      prompt: "select_account",
    })

    var authInstance = await window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    var signedIn = authInstance.isSignedIn.get()
    if (signedIn) {
      // handleLogin is my own function for calling our backend server
      //  and doing other login related stuff
      await handleLogin(authInstance.currentUser.get())
    }

    // I am using a custom button with attachClickHandler()
    // https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauthattachclickhandlercontainer_options_onsuccess_onfailure
    let signInElement = window.document.getElementById("signInButton")
    if (signInElement) {
      attachElementToCallback(signInElement, handleLogin)
    }

 })               
}
```