# How to detect if a user is signed in on page load with Google Sign In

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I'm using this simple code as shown here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button

```
<script>
function renderSignInButton() {
    gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
      'scope': 'profile',
      'width': 220,
      'height': 40,
      'longtitle': true,
      'theme': 'dark',
      'prompt': 'select_account',
      'onsuccess': onSignIn,
      'onfailure': onSignInFailed
    });
  }
</script>

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderSignInButton" async defer></script>
```

All works fine with Signing in and it remembers the sign in state when the user comes back to the page later.

PROBLEM:  How do I detect when a user arrives at the page and is NOT currently signed in?  (The button is rendered but the success or failure handlers never fire so I'm not clear where/how to check for the current sign in state)

I would think it should be straightforward, but the various solutions I've searched for and tried are not working.

Answer (score 0):

This answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60084966/6281777

Only edit I made was to call window.gapi.auth2.init with no options as they conflict with the options already set by gapi.signin2.render.

So, within the onload specified here:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderSignInButton" async defer></script>
```

The check for not signedIn looks like this:

```
async function renderSignInButton() {
    gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
      'scope': 'profile',
      'width': 220,
      'height': 40,
      'longtitle': true,
      'theme': 'dark',
      'prompt': 'select_account',
      'onsuccess': onSignIn,
      'onfailure': onSignInFailed
    });

    //BEGIN CHECK IF USER IS NOT SIGNED IN
    window.gapi.load('auth2', async () => {
      window.auth2 = await window.gapi.auth2.init({
      });
      var authInstance = await window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
      var signedIn = authInstance.isSignedIn.get();
      if (!signedIn) {
        console.log("USER IS NOT SIGNED IN");
        //do stuff
      }
    })
    //END CHECK IF USER IS SIGNED IN

}
```